# Change timeout in L2CAP Bluetooth in C

Tags: c

I try to change timeout in L2CAP by using set_flus_timeout() method and when Iam debugging the code in above function I can see that i got err=-1

this is the function:

```
   int set_flush_timeout(bdaddr_t *ba, int timeout)
    {
        int err = 0, dd;
        struct hci_conn_info_req *cr = 0;
        struct hci_request rq = { 0 };

        struct {
            uint16_t handle;
            uint16_t flush_timeout;
        } cmd_param;

        struct {
            uint8_t  status;
            uint16_t handle;
        } cmd_response;

        // find the connection handle to the specified bluetooth device
        cr = (struct hci_conn_info_req*) malloc(
                sizeof(struct hci_conn_info_req) + 
                sizeof(struct hci_conn_info));
        bacpy( &cr->bdaddr, ba );
        cr->type = ACL_LINK;
        dd = hci_open_dev( hci_get_route( &cr->bdaddr ) );
        if( dd < 0 ) {
            err = dd;
            goto cleanup;
        }
        err = ioctl(dd, HCIGETCONNINFO, (unsigned long) cr );
        if( err ) goto cleanup;

        // build a command packet to send to the bluetooth microcontroller
        cmd_param.handle = cr->conn_info->handle;
        cmd_param.flush_timeout = htobs(timeout);
        rq.ogf = OGF_HOST_CTL;
        rq.ocf = 0x28;
        rq.cparam = &cmd_param;
        rq.clen = sizeof(cmd_param);
        rq.rparam = &cmd_response;
        rq.rlen = sizeof(cmd_response);
        rq.event = EVT_CMD_COMPLETE;

        // send the command and wait for the response
        err = hci_send_req( dd, &rq, 0 );
        if( err ) goto cleanup;

        if( cmd_response.status ) {
            err = -1;
            errno = bt_error(cmd_response.status);
        }

    cleanup:
        free(cr);
        if( dd >= 0) close(dd);
        return err;
    }
```

I dont understand why?! I am using in Bluez.

please help me

David

Answer (score 1):

In the code you posted `err` can be set to -1 in 4 places.

1. `hci_open_dev( hci_get_route( &cr->bdaddr ) )

   `hci_open_dev` fails in two places

   1. If the socket crreation fails
   2. If the socket binding fails
2. `ioctl(dd, HCIGETCONNINFO, (unsigned long) cr )`

   See Errors section of [ioctl manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ioctl)
3. `hci_send_req( dd, &rq, 0 )`

   1. Getting socket options failed
   2. Setting socket options failed
   3. `hci_send_cmd` failed
   4. If poll leads to timeout or poll fails (returns -1)
   5. If read fails (returns -1)
   6. If the command response status is 1
4. cmd_response.status is 1`

See [hci.c](http://bluez.sourcearchive.com/documentation/4.40-2/hci_8c-source.html%5d) for further information.

In order to narrow down which place exactly set `err` to -1, use a debugger like `gdb` or `printf` statements in each of the 4 places in your code.

For more information on debugging with gdb see [here](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_toc.html).

Comment: I don't understand why do I get error, but If you have any idea how to change the flush timeout in bluetooh L2CAP I will be glad.

thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error while calling the ioctl(..., HCIGETCONNINFO, ...) and discovered the problem was the bt adapter did not have any active connection while calling ioctl() syscall.
Is the L2CAP socket connected?
In my case perror() reported "Not connected" or something similar
You should anyway follow the suggestion and check where you are getting the error (gdb is your friend ;-) )
Hope this helps

Ciao
Sergio